# How to configure WebStom with Webpack for Angular2 (cannot find module)?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, angular, webpack

I am using WebStorm and webpack and since my tsconfig is set to node_modules, WebStorm does not recongnize the paths for any of my modules and thus the TypeScript that is bundled with WebStorm emits errors as you can see in my attachments...

tsconfig.json

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noResolve": false
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "./**/*.ts",
    "!./node_modules"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "buildOnSave": true
}
```

Errors in Webstorm:

[image]

wondering if there is a way to make Webstorm be Webpack and ng2 aware using TypeScript...

TX

Sean

Comment: tx for the reply... it was just fixed in WebStorm latest EA... regards

Answer (score 1):

tx for the reply... it was just fixed in WebStorm latest EA... version 144.3143.5 regards